# Finding arc length without radius

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

Hello geniuses of the math-ternet, a 10th grade student I tutor in math showed me [this exam question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy4Gv.png) (ignore the scribblings). It asks for the arc length of RST, even though no radius, circumference, or any measure of length is given, only an angle. I'm stumped. How do you solve for an arc length with no unit / length to reference? Am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Edit: It's unlikely that the teacher "missed" a variable because on the same test, [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ydxf.png) was also asked. It's the same as the first question, just asking for angle from arc length this time.

Comment: $x^\circ$ corresponds to $~\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{180}~$ radians.  Further, the arc length $[RT]$ corresponds to an arc represented by $(2 \times 52^\circ)$.  The desired arc length, in radians, of $[RST]$ corresponds to the complete circumference, in radians, minus the arc represented by $(2 \times 52^\circ)$.

Comment: @user480985, question asks not arc length of RST but angular measure of arc RST, which does not require knowing radius to find.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually say arc length but rather arc **measure**, which is simply the angle measure if you connected the two points on the circle to the center in radians, so convert to radians and use inscribed angle to solve for that angle.

The answer by user1047209 explains that. (Sorry for the lack of a diagram I don't actually know how to add one...but the main point is just that its the angle, not length, so no measurement of length is necessary)

Edit: in the second link you sent the teacher is straight up wrong (I think I'm only in high school too though), radians are not a measure of length, so arc length can't be in radians

Comment: isn't arc measure between A and B expressed as mAB? How does mABC make sense? how do you measure an angle (arc measure) with 4 points - center, A, B, and C?

Comment: for the measuring angle question, it is not the angle between center A B and C, it is the arc that contains A B and C. So you would really just be measuring the angle between A C and the center but on the side that contains the point B

Image of what I'm trying to say: https://imgur.com/a/npmQ5px (basically this is how the guy above me solved it, but the picture shows what part they are referring to, not RT but RST).

Okay so...I just realized comments can only be edited after 5 minutes oops. So I just deleted the previous comments and combined them into this one pls don't downvote me :((

Answer (score 0):

Accordding to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) or actually the theorem about the inscribed angle, the arc RT must be twice as big as the given $52^°$. We therefore calculate:
$2\cdot 52^° = \frac{104^° \cdot 2\pi}{360^°}$, which is equal to $\frac{26}{45} \pi$.
Subtracting it from $2 \pi$ yields $\frac{64}{45} \pi$, therefore A) is the correct answer.

Comment: How did you infer that the teacher wanted the angle of RT from "measure of [arc] RST"?

Comment: Well, this is simply applied logic, since we are on a circle and the arc RST is the part missing towards $2\pi$ wrt. to "RT", so we can just use this information.